# Android spinner not displayed

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

I have this part of code:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
...
    scanNextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
    ...
           formNextButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View v) {
           ...
           ArrayList<String> spinnerArray =  new ArrayList<String>();
                                spinnerArray.add("item1");
                                spinnerArray.add("item2");
                                Spinner sItems = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.prodCategory);
                                ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, spinnerArray);
                                adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                                sItems.setAdapter(adapter);
```

but the spinner choices aren't display when I run the application. Why?

Comment: Please Provide proper code.

Comment: Must check that Spinner id must be same name as `prodCategory` and move line `Spinner sItems = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.prodCategory);` to `onCreate()`.

Comment: Could you please provide better code, because the last part works perfectly in my Eclipse.